# What is "parser rule 'channels' not allowed in lexer" error in this ANTLR 4 Lexer file?

Tags: java, mysql, antlr4

I am trying to build the Parser and Lexer from the MySQL .g4 files at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/mysql. I get the error **"parser rule 'channels' not allowed in lexer"** as demonstrated in the attached image.

[image: This is the error in the Lexer file]

Comment: That makes no sense at all. This is an error in the IDE, not the grammar. Which IDE is that. Try Visual Studio Code with my ANTLR4 extension and it will give you the correct details.

Comment: Maybe this IDE uses an outdated version of ANTLR. Such syntax appeared in 4.5 version: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#channel

Comment: @MikeLischke The IDE is the ANTLR4 plugin for Eclipse. I 'fixed' it by commenting out the channels line and hard-coding the channel numbers where necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lexer-only grammars can only contain lexer rules.  What I think is happening here is that tool you're using is interpreting the "rule" `channels` as a parser rule because it does not begin with an uppercase letter and therefore out of place in this lexer-only grammar.

However, Mike's comment is correct.  This `channels` construct is (currently) a valid ANTLR grammar for a lexer file. [See this page.](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/grammars.md).  It is supposed to go in the the lexer grammar file, and so the only thing I can surmise about the error you're getting is that the tool (IDE) you're using doesn't understand the `channels` custom specification syntax.

Be aware that not every grammar in that github list is perfect, and is not part of ANTLR proper, but are contributed by various authors and sometimes different versions of ANTLR than the one you're using at any given moment.

Comment: `channels` is not a rule, but the list of channels supprted by a grammar and **only** valid in a lexer grammar.

Comment: Does it go in the Parser file?

Comment: No, the `channels` command is a only allowed in lexer grammars.